# React Typescript | How can I enable dark mode using tailwind?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tailwind-css

I got stuck at enabling dark mode for my react/typescript element.
I created a Context.Provider to switch light/dark mode for the entire app, but the toggle does not work at all. If anybody knows how to fix it, please help.

This is the ThemeContext and ContextProvider

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

type ThemeName = 'light' | 'dark' | string
type ThemeContextType = {
  theme: ThemeName
  setTheme: (name: ThemeName) => void
}

const getInitialTheme = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage) {
    const storedPrefs = window.localStorage.getItem('color-theme')
    if (typeof storedPrefs === 'string') {
      return storedPrefs
    }

    const userMedia = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme:dark)')
    if (userMedia.matches) {
      return 'dark'
    }
  }
  // returning default theme here
  return 'light'
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>({} as ThemeContextType)

export const ThemeProvider = ({ initialTheme, children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme)


  const rawSetTheme = theme => {
//Updated rawSetTheme to theme above//
    const root = window.document.documentElement
    const isDark = theme === 'dark'

    root.classList.remove(isDark ? 'light' : 'dark')
    root.classList.add(theme)

    localStorage.setItem('color-theme', theme)
  }

  if (initialTheme) {
    rawSetTheme(initialTheme)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    rawSetTheme(theme)
  }, [theme])

  return <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
}
```

And this is the index.tsx.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider>
    <App />, document.getElementById('root')
  </ThemeProvider>
)
```

And this is the Toggle

```
export const DarkModeToggle: VFC<Props> = memo(() => {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext)

  function isDark() {
    return theme === 'dark'
  }

  function toggleTheme(e) {
    setTheme(e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'light')
  }
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
      <label htmlFor='unchecked' className='mt-3 inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer'>
        <span className='relative'>
          <span className='block w-10 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full shadow-inner'></span>
          <span
            className={`${
              theme === 'dark' ? 'bg-indigo-400 transform translate-x-full' : 'bg-white'
            } absolute block w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1  rounded-full shadow inset-y-0 left-0 focus-within:shadow-outline transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out`}
          >
            <input
              id='darkmode'
              onClick={e => toggleTheme(e)}
              type='checkbox'
              checked={isDark()}
              className='absolute opacity-0 w-0 h-0'
            />
          </span>
        </span>
        <span className='ml-3 text-sm'>{theme === 'dark' ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  )
})
```

**Updated:** I changed the 'rawSetTheme' to 'theme' for variable, but it returns an error" in App.tsx as below. If you have any suggestions, it would be very appreciated.

```
Property 'initialTheme' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }' but required in type '{ initialTheme: any; children: any; }'.  TS2741

     7 | export default function App() {
     8 |   return (
  >  9 |     <ThemeProvider>
       |      ^
    10 |       <Router />
    11 |     </ThemeProvider>
    12 |   )
```

Comment: What's the CSS you have to apply this theme?

Comment: Assuming `rawSetTheme`  is hit every time and the class values changes on the HTML tag and local storage.

Comment: Here is the index.css (omitted excess for characters limit)

:root {
  @apply light;
} 
.dark {
  --color-bg-primary: #1F2937;
}

.light {
  --color-bg-primary: #F3F4F6;
}

Comment: Why do you have sass in css file?

Comment: This is tailwind. I added dark/light color scheme so I can switch. 
darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: {
        primary: 'var(--color-bg-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--color-bg-secondary)',
      },
      textColor: {
        accent: 'var(--color-text-accent)',
        primary: 'var(--color-text-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--color-text-secondary)',
      },```

Comment: But the css file can't handle these SASS file content. Not sure how this will work for you.

Comment: It works ok on my end. So I assumed the problem is related to the context or typescript area, i guess...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237856/discussion-between-chi-and-sanish-joseph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the comment. I could fix it. It was just a small error of Toggle.tsx. The tailwind extends setting is also working fine.

```
export const DarkModeToggle: VFC<Props> = memo(() => {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext)
  
  return (

    <div className='flex flex-col'>
      <label className='mt-3 inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer'>
        <span className='relative'>
          <span className='block w-10 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full shadow-inner'></span>
          <span
            className={`${
              theme === 'dark' ? 'bg-indigo-400 transform translate-x-full' : 'bg-white'
            } absolute block w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1  rounded-full shadow inset-y-0 left-0 focus-within:shadow-outline transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out`}
          >
            <input onClick={()=>setTheme(theme==='dark'?'light':'dark')} className='absolute opacity-0 w-0 h-0' />
          </span>
        </span>
        <span className='ml-3 text-sm'>{theme === 'dark' ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  )
})
```